# Using query string to get a response from controller and displaying it in same page

Tags: spring-mvc, query-string

I am developing a dashboard using Spring MVC. I have a jsp page(For ex: localhost:8080/example). I have a form in that page which has a input box and button. When I click on the button, I need to call the controller to give the output which should be displayed in same page. I am using query string to get the output(localhost:8080/example?sender=hello). I need to display the response in the same page without losing the text input value I entered. How do I do that??

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is use javascript.

Utilise .load() function to call the relevant URL within application, get the rendered page and then put it within a div that will host it.

Your other option is to get the JSON values and insert them manually into the relevant HTML elements you wish populated on your dashboard.